# Windows Time Zones

Tags: windows, timezone

Linux (Unix) has a database where you can easily check for changes to a time zone. Just download https://www.iana.org/time-zones

On Windows, all I can find is a blog https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/bg-p/DSTBlog

Here they indicate when there is a change in some time zone. But, how can I know the link that I have to download to have the correct time zones? or how can I verify that my time zone is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that is a bad thing. Anyhow, there is no download link because updates to the timezone library come via the normal patching process. If your windows is properly maintained, the general assumption would be that the time zone is up to date - whatever this means (as in: It is possible, theoretically, that an update was not done yet).

MS basically does all the updating via patching, i.e. KB3192321 (just as an example). Hence no database available for download.